# Laravel: Passing Variable / Parameter from blade.php View to a function in controller via Route

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-10, php-8.2

I'm trying to pass a loop iterator variable `$user` from my view's `Datatable` (on clicking edit button) to a controller function using a `Route`.

My Route in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/add_all',[AddPersInfoController::class,'add_all'])->name('add_all');
```

My Controller function:

```
public  function add_all($user_id){ 
...
}
```

Datatable code in `draft.blade.php` View:

```
 @php $i=1 @endphp
                      @foreach($pers as $user)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$i}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->user_type ?? 'N/A'}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->rank->name ?? 'N/A'}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->name ?? 'N/A'}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{route('add_all',[$user->id])}}"><button class="btn btn-icon btn-primary">  <i class="demo-pli-pencil fs-5"></i> </button> </a></td>
                      </tr> 
                      @php $i++; @endphp
                      @endforeach
```

Where the `$pers` variable is sent to this view via another route using `compact()` function.

I have tried passing specific var like `[$user->id]` and a different syntax like `$user` but nothing works. All of these give the same error.

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AddPersInfoController::add_all(), 0 passed
```

There are other answers who try to suggest using `URL::to` instead of `href`.
But I want a solution using `href` only.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've also tried `{{route('add_all',[$user])}}` ;
Still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route definition does not expect any parameters. You need to define a parameter in your route definition in `web.php` file.

```php
Route::get('/add_all/{user}', [AddPersInfoController::class,'add_all'])->name('add_all');
```

In the above code, `{user}` is a placeholder for the parameter that you want to pass to the `add_all` method in your `AddPersInfoController`. Now, your `add_all` method in the `AddPersInfoController` should be able to receive the `$user` parameter.

```php
public function add_all($user) { 
    // ...
}
```

And in your blade file, you can pass the `$user->id` as a parameter to the route.

```php
<a href="{{ route('add_all', ['user' => $user->id]) }}">
    <button class="btn btn-icon btn-primary">
        <i class="demo-pli-pencil fs-5"></i>
    </button>
</a>
```

Comment: I tried that as well but then my homepage throws an error that expected `parameters` in the said `Route` are missing.